# How to make an XNA application reload itself

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to make the game go fullscreen the moment you press the button F, but it doesn't work, I'm thinking because it has to first reload the application for it to take affect, so how do I do that?

Code:

```
public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    IsMouseVisible = true;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = WINDOW_WIDTH;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.F))
    {
        WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280;
        WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720;              
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: Doing this 60 times per second might not be that wise. consider storing keyboardstate in a property (PreviousKeyboardState) at the END of you update (just before base.update, but after all other logic) and making sure the user is not holding down the f-key by checking that PreviousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.F)

Comment: How do I do that? I did the sort of same thing with the mouse click but how do I do it with a button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some light research (googled 'XNA 4 toggle fullscreen'), and found that there is a ToggleFullScreen-method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager.togglefullscreen.aspx

I have also applied the fix I mentioned earlier in a comment, to avoid toggling fullscreen every frame

```
public KeyboardState PreviousKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
public Boolean FullscreenMode = false;

public Vector2 WindowedResolution = new Vector2(800,600);
public Vector2 FullscreenResolution = new Vector2(1280, 720);

public void UpdateDisplayMode(bool fullscreen, Vector2 resolution)
{
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = (int)resolution.X;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = (int)resolution.Y;
    graphics.IsFullScreen = fullscreen;
    graphics.ApplyChanges();
}

public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    IsMouseVisible = true;

    UpdateDisplayMode(FullscreenMode);
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    var keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();


    if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.F) && PreviousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.F))
    {
        if (FullscreenMode)
            UpdateDisplayMode(false, WindowedResolution);
        else
            UpdateDisplayMode(true, FullscreenResolution);
    }

    PreviousKeyboardState = keyboardState;
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But, I also want it to change the resolution of the screen, if I leave it at 800 x 600, the fullscreen res is going to be 800 x 600. I tried changing WINDOW_WIDTH/HEIGHT in the if statement, but it didn't work, any ideas?

Comment: Edited answer to incorporate resolution change. I hardcoded the values, so you will probably want to use your WINDOW_HEIGHT/WIDTH or something.

Comment: It worked, woo hoo! But if I want to toggle it back? I tried to do that, but it just toggles fullscreen and doesn't change resolution back to a window smaller than the screen size.

Comment: I have now added ability to update resolution in my post. But this is not normally something you would want to do, as you might need several versions of your assets for the different resolutions. Also; Awesome if you could accept my answer if it works :)

Comment: I used the code exactly as you said, now the actual program won't open, I try opening it and it builds, goes to debug mode and goes back to normal mode.

Comment: @user3074243 sorry, that might be because of using the method in the constructor. These things are pretty hard to do when I don't have XNA on my day-to-day computer so I can't really test the stuff i suggest myself... Pretty sure it will work if you remove the call from the constructor or something like that (I think it is calling the ApplyChanges() before initialization that causes it)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not updating is because when you press the 'F' key you just set your variables to fullscreen size.
In order to actually resize the window you have to do the same as in your constructor:

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = WINDOW_WIDTH;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
```

in addition to that you may also want to set `graphics.IsFullScreen = true;`

Comment: Still not working, I tried putting `this.` in front of the graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth/graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @user3074243 Try to add `graphics.ApplyChanges();` after setting width and height